# C compiler error: expected parameter declarator

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

https://github.com/noyesno/awka

For the above repo, I got the following error when I try to compile it on macOS (gcc is just clang). I have no idea how to fix the problem according to the error message. It compiles fine on Linux.

I also tried the real gcc from Homebrew to compile the package. It also show the same error. How can I fix this problem on macOS?

```
$ ./configure
$ make
...
gcc -O -Dawka_LIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -Dawka_INCDIR=\"/usr/local/include\"   -c -o print.o print.c
print.c:52:11: error: expected parameter declarator
int PROTO(sprintf, (char *, const char *,...)) ;
          ^
print.c:52:11: error: expected ')'
print.c:52:11: note: to match this '('
print.c:52:11: error: conflicting types for '__builtin___sprintf_chk'
int PROTO(sprintf, (char *, const char *,...)) ;
          ^
print.c:52:11: note: '__builtin___sprintf_chk' is a builtin with type 'int (char *, int, unsigned long, const char *, ...)'
3 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: print.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/private/tmp/awka/awka'
make: *** [Makefile:48: awka_exe] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to spend ages on this, but it looks as though configure is gripping stdio.h looking for sprintf. It is unable to find it in the header, and so it adds the #define:

```
NO_SPRINTF_IN_STDIO
```

which it sets to 1, and uses it to add its own prototype for sprintf. Unfortunately, this appears to be a macro in this case, which replaces sprintf with '__builtin___sprintf_chk' instead (which has additional string length checks by the looks of it).

Possible solutions:

1. Comment out the line in print.c, and make sure stdio.h is included somewhere.
2. After running configure, search for where it defines NO_SPRINTF_IN_STDIO and set that var to 1?
3. Fix the configure to so a more rigorous test?

Comment: I tried 1. It works. I am not sure how to get 2&3 work properly. Ideally, it seems that 3 should the most appropriate fix.